# Find an infinity ring with a finite characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find an infinity ring with finite characteristic p, which has following properties:

(i) is not commutative

(ii)  is a field

(iii)  does not have unit

I think that the (ii) can be field of fractions using  integral domain ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }_p[x]$ set of all polynomials over the field $  {\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} }_p$

But I cannot find other examples. Probbaly some sequences with finite non-zero elements can work but I have no idea how to finish it.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: $X(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\langle X,Y\rangle$ works for (i) and (iii), where $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\langle X,Y\rangle$ is the [free algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) generated by $X$ and $Y$, or non-commutative polynomials, if you want to call it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (i), take the ring of $n\times n$ matrices for some $n>1$, with entries in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$. For (iii), take $p\Bbb Z_{p^2}[x]$.

Comment: I have one more question. Is there any "simpler" example for (ii)? Thanks!

Comment: @Waney No, I think the field of rational functions in one variable with coefficients from $\Bbb Z_p$ is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $2\mathbb Z_{2p}$ actually does have a unit, namely $p+1$. It might be better to take $p\mathbb Z_{p^2}$.

Comment: @MarcPaul Chinese remainder theorem says you're right. Modulo $p^2$ it is.

Comment: Now I am little bit confused. I am trying to do it on example. First of all I take p=3 and use the orginal form $pZ_2p$ it means that $3Z_6$ is set {0,3,6,9,12,15} how I know that the characteristic is 3, and why it has unit, since 3+1=4 is not in set. Now I am trying to do same with $3Z_9$ is set {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24} how I know that the characteristic is 3. Probbaly I do not understand the notation or somethin other. I am sorry. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Waney $3\Bbb Z_9$ is the set $\{3,6,0\}$, since in $\Bbb Z_9$ we have $3=12=21$ and so on, so we don't have to list any of the other elements. The ring has additive group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3$ (so the characteristic is $3$), and _any_ product is equal to $0$, so there cannot be a unit.

Comment: @Arthur  Thank you very much now  everything is clear.